# Как скопировать текст с определенного символа из Memo?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  k: integer;
begin
  for k:=1 to memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
  begin
    if AnsiPos('%', Memo1.Lines.Strings[k]) <>0 then
     begin
    //  Edit1.Text := ?
     end;
  end;
end;
```

Есть цикл в Button, который смотрит каждую строку в Memo. Если находится первый символ '%', но как сделать чтобы в Edit добавились все символы идущие после него до тех пор, пока не встретится такой же символ?

Пример текста в Memo:

> %Здесь какой-то текст, необходимый для того чтобы его куда-то перенести.%

Что должно оказаться в Edit:

> Здесь какой-то текст, необходимый для того чтобы его куда-то перенести.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте сделаем функцию, которая принимает строку текста и возвращает все что есть между %%:

```
function GetTextInPercent(aLine: string): string;
var
  i1, i2: Integer;
begin
  i1 := Pos('%', aLine) + 1;
  i2 := PosEx('%', aLine, i1);
  Result := Copy(aLine, i1, i2 - i1);
end;
```

P.S. Естественно вам надо будет предусмотреть поведение для случаев, когда в тексте не два знака `%`, а больше или меньше.

Comment: Пишет: Undeclared identifier: 'PosEx'

Comment: В секцию `uses` нужно добавить модуль `StrUtils`

Comment: Не выгружает несколько строк. Видимо потому, что превышает число доступных символов. Как быть?

Comment: @Ник Это из-за переносов строк. Добавьте уточнение в вопрос или задайте новый )